# cycling through latex math mode and equation

Tags: elisp, latex, auctex

Is there a way to cycle through \( x=1 \), \[ x=1\] and 
\begin{equation}
x=1
\end{equation}

in any latex package? I find this function practical but I didn't know how to implement using elisp or maybe someone has already done that?

Comment: I imagine I could write something to do this, but how would the function differentiate between math and some text that's simply in parens?

Comment: @GJStein sorry i forget to use double backslash to display backslash, maybe that is your question, because I never use dollar sign to start a math environment

Comment: Are you using `AucTeX`? If not, I'd recommend it. If so, there are some built in commands which would help out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will do what you want:

```
(defun cycle-texmath () 

  (if (texmathp)
    (save-excursion
      (setq env (car texmathp-why))
      (if (string= env "equation") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\begin{equation}") (replace-match "\\[" t t)
        (search-forward "\\end{equation}") (replace-match "\\]" t t)))
      (if (string= env "\\[") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\[") (replace-match "\\(" t t)
        (search-forward "\\]") (replace-match "\\)" t t)))
      (if (string= env "\\(") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\(") (replace-match "\\begin{equation}" t t)
        (search-forward "\\)") (replace-match "\\end{equation}" t t)))
  )))

(eval-after-load "latex"
   '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") (lambda () (interactive) (cycle-texmath)))
     ))
```

It relies on the `texmathp` and `texmathp-why` functions which are built into `AucTeX` to determine if the point is within a math mode and which indicators are used to invoke it. I've bound it to `C-c t`, but feel free to replace that with whatever you'd like.

#### EDIT:

After posing this as [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/change-escape-behavior-when-inside-latex-equations) to handle the edge case of being within a `text{}` environment, the updated version of the code is here:

```el
(defun cycle-texmath ()
  (save-excursion
    (while (member (TeX-current-macro) '("text"))
      (backward-char))
    (when (texmathp)
      (let ((env (car texmathp-why)))
        (cond
         ((string= env "equation")
          (search-backward "\\begin{equation}")
          (replace-match "\\[" t t)
          (search-forward "\\end{equation}")
          (replace-match "\\]" t t))
         ((string= env "\\[")
          (search-backward "\\[")
          (replace-match "\\(" t t)
          (search-forward "\\]")
          (replace-match "\\)" t t))
         ((string= env "\\(")
          (search-backward "\\(")
          (replace-match "\\begin{equation}" t t)
          (search-forward "\\)")
          (replace-match "\\end{equation}" t t)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works exactly the way I want, and beside I learn some basic elisp buffer manip by looking at the code.

Comment: Well there is an issue with things like \[xy=1 \text{ where \(y=2\)} \], but it is rare.

Comment: I posed this edge case as a (SO question)[http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/change-escape-behavior-when-inside-latex-equations], and I've modified the code to handle it in accordance with the response. Be sure to upvote the correct answer there.

Comment: thanks a lot, in fact, I didn't state the edge case correctly. Actually when I am writing latex, frequently I need to change an inline math environment into display math, since it looks better; or sometimes I need to make a ref to some displayed equation, that's why changing \\[\\] into \begin{eq}etc is handy. So the question is, in a display math style like this \\[ xy=1 \text{ where \\(y=2\\)}\\], invoking cycle-math will produce \\(xy=1 \text{ where \\( y=2\\) \\) then comes to \begin{eq} \text{ where \\( y=2 \end{eq} } \\).