# Change escape behavior when inside LaTeX equations

Tags: latex, auctex

I recently [wrote a function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/cycling-through-latex-math-mode-and-equation/13936#13936) which could cycle through LaTeX math delimiters. It relies on the `texmathp` function, built into AucTeX, which will return `t` if the point is inside an equation region. In addition, I use the `texmathp-why` function in order to determine what the math environment is (which was important to answering the posed question).

However, it was pointed out by the asker that the function does not work when the point is inside `\text{}` inside the equation (which I assume is intentional behavior within AucTeX). Is there a simple way to avoid this escape, or should I write a work around in the function to account for this?

Comment: @Name The question involved rotating through the "commands" which signify that one is inside a math environment: `\[`, `\(` and `\begin{equation`'.

Comment: Is the environment`\text{}` the sole exception inside?

Comment: @Name I believe that it is.

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using?  For me (using AUCTeX 11.88), `texmathp` returns nil if point is inside the argument of `\text` and other similar macros (see `texmathp-tex-commands-default` variable).

Comment: @giordano It does return `nil` when it's inside `\text`, that was the edge case I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question, I thought you wanted to get `nil` inside `\text{}` and I didn't understand why it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding the line `(while (member (TeX-current-macro) '("text")) (backward-char))` to your code does the job:

```
(defun cycle-texmath ()
(save-excursion (progn
(while (member (TeX-current-macro) '("text")) (backward-char))
(if (texmathp) (progn
      (setq env (car texmathp-why))
      (if (string= env "equation") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\begin{equation}") (replace-match "\\[" t t)
        (search-forward "\\end{equation}") (replace-match "\\]" t t)))
      (if (string= env "\\[") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\[") (replace-match "\\(" t t)
        (search-forward "\\]") (replace-match "\\)" t t)))
      (if (string= env "\\(") (progn 
        (search-backward "\\(") (replace-match "\\begin{equation}" t t)
        (search-forward "\\)") (replace-match "\\end{equation}" t t)))
  )))))
```

Comment: I've moved the `save-excursion` function to include the while loop, but otherwise, this code is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!